# Angular 2-4: downloading different ui components based on user privileges

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, user-interface, model-view-controller, components

I know Angular 2-4 represents a new way to build large web applications via components. So, you can code all your frontend in Typescript -i mean, all your UI- with Angular and then build this project and put it as a static content into a Java Web project for example. In other words, we are putting all our GUI content in hands of Angular so it will be loaded in any browser no matter which kind of user access our application.

My point is: what happen with Angular when you expect your user has different roles or access privileges, so you UI must be different between users. But your UI is 100% downloaded into the browser so a clever user can access the HTML code/component of a UI for which he/she doesn't have access or permissions.

How we can control this problem with Angular? Or if it is not possible, do I have to migrate to a monolithic architecture like spring MVC? Or try to migrate the project for a server side rendering like Universal?

Thanks for any support.

Comment: You can still prevent the user from retrieving data or invoking actions.

Comment: But what about views or ui components? That's the matter, my friend. I don't find an appropiate way to prevent users from loading all my views, just only all the views his privileges permit.

Comment: View is only a layer on top of Your API, smart user can user your API directly. You pointed that user can somehow use downloaded client code to do things he is not permitted to. I think You shouldn't bother about that, but I might be wrong. I'm trying to understand Your point of view and motivation.

Comment: See it:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/DCKmPjLYM7o

Comment: My point is that all our .ts files are loaded into the browser after compilation and in .js type. These ui views contains the views of all our entire application (supose its like an Odoo application with several functionalities) and a specific user just only need to know the views of his module, not the views of the entire application.

Comment: Oh well, then I think you can set up route guards and lazy module loading.